# Taxonomy translation Localize option not working correctly. thoughts?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual drupal 7 site. I have a series of taxonomy terms to choose from. I have the il8n Translate Taxonomy enabled and using it.

For my taxonomy I have selected "Localize. Terms are common for all languages, but their name and description may be localized."

However, despite being able to use the translate interface to correctly translate them, the terms still show up in English, the default language, regardless of what language I am viewing the content in. Here are links to the issues. Please see the tables.

```
http://tourismbuilder1.hokkaido-select.com/content/dai-ichi-takimotokan

http://tourismbuilder1.hokkaido-select.com/ja/content/%E7%AC%AC%E4%B8%80%E6%BB%9D%E6%9C%AC%E9%A4%A8
```

Thoughts as to why?

EDIT:
I found this link to the issue, which is unresolved.
drupal.org/node/1070256

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this is to change the taxonomy link preferences under 'Manage Display' in the content type - here is a link to a thread on the issue.

http://drupal.org/node/1070256